# How to insert values into MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following piece of code that I am trying to execute:

```
// Connecting to the database "db_name"
$connection = mysql_connect('......com', 'login', 'password', 'db_name'); 
if (!$connection) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo "Connection Successful";


// creating a query 
mysql_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `customers` (`FirstName`, `Lastname`, `Username`, `Email`, 

`Password`) VALUES ($firstname, $lastname, $username,$email,$password);");
mysql_close($connection);

// printing to the screen
echo "Welcome $lastname . You have successfully logged in!";
```

The result I get is the following

```
Connection SuccessfulWelcome . You have successfully logged in! Add another user
```

However, there is nothing in the MySQL. No entries have been inserted. I get the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /hermes/bosweb/web241/b2418/ipg........com/login_action.php on line 28 20130143043: chmmmmm.com/login_action.php PHP Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /hermes/bosweb/web241/b2418/ipg.e........com/login_action.php on line 28
```

Comment: Please see the [documentation](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) it is all clearly laid out (as well as the deprecation notice).

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Answer (score 4):

Please read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) on `mysqli`.
Do not use `mysql` functions as they are deprecated.

When using `mysqli_query()` you do in fact need to provide the `$connection` as the first parameter. Using `mysqli` the following line of code will work as long as you don't have any SQL syntax errors.

```
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `customers` (`FirstName`, `Lastname`, `Username`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES ($firstname, $lastname, $username, $email, $password);");
```

The following is proper syntax for creating a mysqli connection, also.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'DB');

if (!$connection) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about sql injection

Comment: Well, how would I go about protecting him from that? The OP obviously doesn't understand what he's doing right now.

Comment: @Jhawins, nevertheless, it is good to mention. It is better that the OP is informed, since that is better than their not knowing at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
// creating a query
// resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `customers` (`FirstName`, `Lastname`, `Username`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES ($firstname, $lastname, $username,$email,$password);", $connection);


//mysql_query(STRING $query, RESOURCE $link_identifier);

$sql_query = "INSERT INTO `customers` (`FirstName`, `Lastname`, `Username`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES ($firstname, $lastname, $username,$email,$password);"
mysql_query($sql_query, $connection);
```

Comment: What is the change you've made?

Comment: I swapped connection and query ... like shown, first query, then connection, not the other way round.

Comment: you should say that in the answer, not in a comment. Great answers teach, not just fix somebody's code.

Comment: Should tell him the dangers of using a depreciated (about to be removed) function such as this. Don't just let ignorance fly, correct it.

Comment: @Jhawins Why? There are always minimum 5 others that tell this story over and over again ... I try fixing errors.

Comment: @djot Did you just ask me why someone shouldn't use a depreciated/soon to be removed function? Because I don't think a question that ridiculous deserves a real answer.

Comment: @djot using a deprecated (also shitty) function is an error. and one that shouldn't be overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

According to the mysql_query syntax, the `$connection` variable should be placed after the actual query. But this is optional.

Also you need to remove the `;` out of the query.

So replace your current line for this:

> mysql_query("INSERT INTO `customers` (`FirstName`, `Lastname`, `Username`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES ($firstname, $lastname, $username,$email,$password)");

Good Luck!

Comment: Should tell him the dangers of using a depreciated (about to be removed) function such as this.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` takes the connection as an optional second parameter. Drop the `$connection` parameter or move it to the second position rather than the first and you should be fine.

Note, too, that this API is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. Consider using the newer [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) API instead.

Comment: It does, but as second argument - not first like here!

Comment: @djot: ooh, thanks! I've never used that feature. Edited to match.

Comment: should I omit it then?

Comment: No. He needs to be using `mysqli_query($connection, $query)`, why entertain ignorance?

Comment: I am pretty sure that I have been using it as the first parameter and it worked just fine. Has anything been changed in PHP>

Comment: @Jhawins: That's why I recommended PDO since I happen to prefer it over MySQLi, but that's another option :)

Comment: There is almost no difference between mysql and mysqli EXCEPT for PHP version and speed

Comment: @Buras: I'm quite confident that the `mysql_query` interface never changed. But `mysqli_query` takes it as an optional *first* parameter rather than second—maybe that's what you're thinking of.